# How to add a value selected from drop down menu to QLineEdit and refresh it when another value is selected in pyqt4

Tags: python, pyqt4

How do I add the value selected from self.cb(QComboBox) to self.b(QLineEdit) and refresh it when I select another value?[For example if I select Genomics from drop down menu this value should appear in QlineEdit(box) and the value should come before I press the submit button.]

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)`enter code here`
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 250,250)
        QtGui.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence("Esc"), self, self.close)
        # Create controls
        self.lbl = QtGui.QLabel('Types of Analysis', self)
        self.lbl.setFont(QtGui.QFont('SansSerif', 15) )
        self.cb = QtGui.QComboBox(self)#drop-down menu
        self.cb.addItems(['Sentiment Analysis', 'Data Cleansing', 'Genomics', 'Integration', 'Visualization'])#contents of drop-down menu
        self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Submit', self)

        self.b=QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.b.move(50,130)

    # Create layout
        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.lbl)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.cb)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.b)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.printingaction)   

        self.show()


    def printingaction(self):
        print 'Current item: {0}'.format( self.cb.currentIndex() ) # ComboBox's index
        print 'Current index: {0}'.format( self.cb.currentText() ) # ComboBox's text



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWindow()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

Comment: `self.cb.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(self.b.setText)`.

Comment: Thank you Sir. It worked@ekhumoro

Comment: What should I do if I have to include another QLineEdit(box) for subject code?Each subject has a subject code(for example Sentiment Analysis has code CS001, Data Cleansing has CS002,etc.).When i select one subject (Sentiment Analysis) its subject code(CS001) should be displayed in the new edit box.What should I do for this problem?